# Close file before moving in python

Tags: python

I have an issue ttying to move a file using shutil.move(), likely because the file is still open. I don't have the problem when run it in debugger ... But when I execute the script I have this error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Here is a block of my code that is causing the issue. How could this be changed to avoid the problem?

```
while len(args) > 0:
    outdir = args.pop()
    indir  = args.pop()
    inouts.append( (indir,outdir) )

    listFile = os.listdir(indir)
    os.chdir(indir)

    for report in listFile:
        abs_report = os.path.abspath(report)
        for line in open(abs_report):
            if header not in line:
                if ref in line:
                    shutil.move(abs_report,Pull)
                    logger.write("File " + report + " has been moved to " + Pull + " at " +  str(datetime.now()) + "\n")
                    break
                else:
                    shutil.move(abs_report,outdir)
                    logger.write("File " + report + " has been moved to " + outdir + " at " + str(datetime.now()) + "\n")
                    break
```

Comment: This is not the place to ask questions when you are blocked from asking on [so]. You should follow their [guidance on question bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: Well ... I understand your point. I was trying to follow their rules and guidance but it still did not allow me to post a question. Hence I did not have a choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get out of the loop before moving the file:

```
listFile = os.listdir(indir)
os.chdir(indir)

for report in listFile:
    abs_report = os.path.abspath(report)
    is_pull = None
    for line in open(abs_report):
        if header not in line:
            is_pull = (ref in line)
            break
    if is_pull is not None:
        if is_pull:
            shutil.move(abs_report,Pull)
            logger.write("File " + report + " has been moved to " + Pull + " at " +  str(datetime.now()) + "\n")
        else:
            shutil.move(abs_report,outdir)
            logger.write("File " + report + " has been moved to " + outdir + " at " + str(datetime.now()) + "\n")
```